# How to include @media in Grunt-Uncss Ignore Function

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, json, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to remove unused CSS on my page.
Everything works pretty good, but unfortunately sometimes a few 
code snippets get removed, although being crucial for the website.

I would like Grunt to ignore all `@media (min-width: ...)` CSS Rules,
but I don't know how to phrase that in my `Gruntfile.JS`.

For Example:

**styles.css**

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col2-set {
    width: 62.2% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 45px;
    padding: 0 90px 0 10px; }
  #order_review {
    width: 37.8%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 45px; } }
```

It's probably pretty simple, but I still didn't find a solution yet.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot!

**Gruntfile.js**

```
uncss: {
        dist: {
        options: {
            ignore       : [
                          /expanded/,
                          /js/,
                          /wp-/,
                          /align/,
                          /admin-bar/,
                          /\w\.in/,
                          /.*footer.*/,
                          /.*footer*/,
                          "^meta\..*",
                          "^\.is-.*",
                          "/^#js/",
                          ".fade",
                          ".nav",
                          ".collapse",
                          ".collapsing"                            
                          ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the comment: `/* uncss:ignore start */` to the line preceding your `@media ...` query in the  *styles.css* file, and also add the closing comment `/* uncss:ignore end */` to the next line following the end of the `@media` query.

Any rule(s) between those two comments will be ignored.

**Example of styles.css:**

```css
/* uncss:ignore start */
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .col2-set {
    width: 62.2% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 45px;
    padding: 0 90px 0 10px;
  }

  #order_review {
    width: 37.8%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
}
/* uncss:ignore end */
```